# Tuple constraint

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to place a tuple-constraint over the following code, when fase is 'E', sp must be at least 2

```
Create table MODULE     
    (
     code   varchar2(6),    
     omschr varchar2(25),   
     fase   varchar2(1) CHECK(fase='P' OR fase='K' OR fase='E'),    
     docent varchar2(3),    
     sp number(1),  
     PRIMARY KEY (code)
    );
```

Comment: try `alter table module add constraint fase_e_sp_must_be_2_or_more check( fase <> 'E' or sp >= 2 )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Create table MODULE     
    (
     code   varchar2(6),    
     omschr varchar2(25),   
     fase   varchar2(1),    
     docent varchar2(3),    
     sp number(1),  
     PRIMARY KEY (code),
     CHECK(fase='P' OR fase='K' OR (fase='E' and sp >= 2))
    );
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: two check constraints? they can be easily merged into one, see kordirko's comment

Comment: @simon: kordirko's comment adds a second constraint to the existing table. It does not merge the two.

Comment: oops, sorry. Anyway I think it should be one constraint.

Comment: @simon: Voila! Two constraints merged into one!